# DDS C++ - Data Distribution Service

Tags: c++, communication, publish-subscribe, data-distribution-service, opensplice

I began to work with C# and I'm trying to test the code that follows for an dds app. I took it from: http://www.laas.fr/files/SLides-A_Corsaro.pdf

```
using System;
/**********************************************************
 * Definition for the TempSensorType
 **********************************************************/
enum TemperatureScale{
    CELSIUS,
    KELVIN,
    FAHRENHEIT
};
struct TempSensorType{
    short id;
    float temp;
    float hum;
    TemperatureScale scale;
};
#pragma keylist TempSensor id

/**********************************************************
 * Main
 **********************************************************/
static public void Main(string[] args){

    dds::Topic<TempSensorType> tsTopic(TempSensorTopic);
    dds::DataWriter<TempSensorType> dw(tsTopic);
    dds::DataReader<TempSensorType> dr(tsTopic);
    dds::SampleInfoSeq info;

    TempSensorSeq data;
    TempSensorType ts;
    ts = new TempSensorType { 1, 25.0F, 65.0F, CELSIUS };
    dw.write(ts);
    ts = new TempSensorType { 2, 26.0F, 70.0F, CELSIUS };
    dw.write(ts);
    ts = new TempSensorType { 3, 27.0F, 75.0F, CELSIUS };
    dw.write(ts);
    sleep(10);
    while (true){
        dr.read(data, info);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); ++i)
            std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Bonjour");
}
```

I start to understand the purpose of each piece of code. But I'm having doubts
about the 4 first lines in the main, thoses that start with "dds::" and I think they are wrong - I'm getting "Identifier expected". If you could help it would be gratefull.

Comment: What exactly is wrong about it? Are you getting exceptions?

Comment: Yes I'm getting noticed "Identifier expected" in all of them. I suppose it's because of the grammar.

Comment: This is C++, not C#.  `#pragma keylist....` is not valid C# code, but it is valid C++.  Same thing with `std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;`

Comment: I don't see anything for including DDS namespace. Also which library are you using?

Comment: Yeah you're right! I will start from the bottom again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it's not valid DDS code. It seems that you're missing the IDL definition (that should explain the `#pragma`) and the code.

You must at first create topics in a .idl file, then build id in order to create classes that you use in your program, and then use program libraries, and everything is missing.

Start to download a DDS implementation, like [OpenDDS](http://opendds.org/) or [Fast-RTPS](https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-RTPS). In addition to this you can check the OpenDDS section in [this site](http://www.wteam.it/) from a working OpenDDS example from scratch.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer helped me to understand better!

Comment: I'm having problems with the installation of OpenDDS... When I build DDS_TAOv2_all I have several errors, it seems dds\ and ace\ are missing. Are they libraries? Where can I find them?

Comment: You don't have it or are not in path. Are you following every step of the tutorial?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm following every step. I think they aren't present. Possible(?)

Comment: When you build dds it must download ace and Tao, so if they are downloaded they should be there

Comment: I did that with the command "configure". I'm using VS2017 could be a problem?

Comment: I'm doing all again

Comment: It worked! The problem was the version of OpenDDS... I'm now doing "First OpenDDS program"